# couldn't find a way to load a 960x624 image on j2me netbeans emulator

Tags: image, netbeans, java-me, midp, lcdui

How to show a full 960x624 image using j2me canvas?

I wouldn't mind to scroll but I don't want it resized.

```
{image = Image.createImage("/earth.png");}
{g.drawImage(image, width, height, Graphics.BOTTOM | Graphics.RIGHT);}
```

doesn't serve the purpose. I want to know if I have any option to get both the horizontal and vertical scroll bars without actually creating them to view the whole image?

The image size should be same as I don't want the TEXT on the image become unreadable.

Comment: what **exactly** happens when you run that code? "doesn't serve the purpose" is too vague problem description to find out what's going wrong

Comment: i m sorry... u know i am NB ... :( . actually i wanted to know if i have any option to get both the horizontal and vertical scroll bars without actually creating themto view the whole image . ... but the image size should be same as i dont want the TEXT on the image become unreadable.

Comment: well MIDP [tag:lcdui] doesn't have API for ready-to use scroll bars, programmers are expected to code these themselves or use 3rd party libraries. By the way, did you consider using UI libraries like [tag:lwuit] or [tag:j2mepolish]?

Comment: no... i will check them out ... and thank you very much for your help.....